# How to conditionally insert a Checkbox in a list item of a customized ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, controltemplate, contentcontrol

I try to make a customized ListView which fills each list item with some stuff and an initial Checkbox if desired. Currently no Checkbox is displayed so I guess my code of the ContentControl stuff is somehow erroneous.

```
<ListView  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Each list item: [Checkbox] Label -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- The code for the optional check box -->
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCheckable}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" />
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <!-- The non-optional test label -->
                        <Label Content="Test Content" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The Code behind:

```cs
public partial class MyListView : ListView {
    public MyListView () {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsCheckable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckableProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsCheckable", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(AppropriatenessWidget), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Comment: Calling XAML code HTML is kind of an insult.

Comment: Well...it worked ;-). Any other hints?

Comment: That `MyItemsSource` construct is horrifying, why does that even exist if you inherit form something with an `ItemsSource`?

Comment: (If anything use `lang-xml` or just `xaml` for the language hints.)

Comment: Valid points! I just removed `MyItemsSource` (the code is slightly different than the original one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{Binding IsCheckable}` binds to the `DataContext` not the control, use for example:

```xml
{Binding IsCheckable,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyListView}}
```

Also i doubt that this subclassing approach is such a good idea, this could easily be handled via an underlying `DataContext`.

Comment: Thank you! I can't remember how much time I already wasted on Binding-DataContext caused problems! If there was only a way to debug incorrect WPF bindings (apart from just seeing the error like you just did)...

Comment: @Bastian: [There is thankfully](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: Thanks again! I will give this article a try tomorrow.

Comment: Refering to your remark concerning subclassing vs. using a `DataContext`. What would be the advantage of prefering the latter over the former?

Comment: @Bastian: You would not need a new class that does nothing.

Comment: I see, well there are actually further responsibilities that I did not mention here.

Comment: I just updated my extended version of the code (including a class hierarchy) which now does not work anymore. I added the code here as the essence of it did not change that much.

Comment: @Bastian: Don't change the question, if you have another problem ask another question. I will not deal with this.

Comment: OK, I guessed that would be allright as it was kind of [an evolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411478/how-to-conditionally-insert-a-checkbox-in-a-list-item-of-a-customized-listview-w) of the original problem.