# How to conditionally insert a Checkbox in a list item of a customized ListView when using class inheritance?

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, controltemplate, contentcontrol

I try to make a customized ListView which fills each list item with some stuff and an initial Checkbox if the concrete inheriting class wishes so. Currently no Checkbox is displayed so I guess my code of the ContentControl stuff is somehow erroneous.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="local:MyListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="some/path/here">
<ListView>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Each list item: [Checkbox] Label -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- The code for the optional check box -->
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCheckable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyListView}}" 
                                                     Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" />
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <!-- The non-optional test label -->
                        <Label Content="Test Content" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
</UserControl>
```

The Code behind:

```
abstract partial class MyListView {
    protected MyListView () {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected abstract bool IsCheckable { get; }
}

// A checkbox should be displayed - but it's not...
public class MyListView1 : MyListView {
    protected bool IsCheckable { get { return true; } }
}

public class MyListView2 : MyListView {
    protected bool IsCheckable { get { return false; } }
}
```

When inspecting the output window I discovered following message (that I don't know how to make use of):

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsCheckable; DataItem='MyListView2' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsCheckable' property not found on 'object' ''MyListView2' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsCheckable; DataItem='MyListView2' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 19 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=IsCheckable; DataItem='MyListView2' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=IsCheckable; DataItem='MyListView2' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

The same error messages appear for MyListView1.
Note that this question arose from the evolution of [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202294/how-to-conditionally-insert-a-checkbox-in-a-list-item-of-a-customized-listview?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: As far as I know the Bindings Source should be a public property but you have protected IsCheckable properties.

Comment: Well that was it! I was not aware of this. What is the reason for this obligation? P.S.: You could write a complete answer so that you would gain the reputation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [msdn Binding Sources Overview:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public  properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation.